# How to add existing language resources to a new project (VS2010)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, localization

It should be an easy task. I have created language resources for German and English in several of my Visual Studio 2010 projects and I want to reuse some of them, because they contain generic strings that I need for every project.

Whenever I try to add an existing resource to my project it ends in a nightmare. The resources aren't recognized at all if I just add the .resx files. Stuff like My.Resources.Languages.UnkownException ist not recognized even though a Resource with that string has been added and the exact same code works in my other program. So somehow the language resource is not recognized as such and all references to it fail

I have found many workarounds like creating new resources and then editing the xml files to copypaste my strings or copypasting every resource related file into my project and then fixing the few errors and warnings that remain. But these are all horrible workarounds.

So, how do I add existing language resources to a project so that I can immediately reuse my Resource strings?

Comment: Open such .resx (double click on it) and change **Access modifier** to **Public** or **Internal**. In a just imported .resx file that field is **No code generation** then you can't access them with _usual_ syntax.

Comment: Oh wow. There was no access modifier option in VS or in the file itself, so I messed some more around and found that if I simply add the Resource.Designer for both languages it works all by its own. I can't quite comprehend how I could possibly have missed that.

Edit: With all the other Resources I used the designer files where added automatically. I guess that is why I didn't think of it.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Never mind. By adding the resource designer I got rid of all the error messages in Visual Studio. When I actually use the assembly then Visual Studio tells me that for the culture or neutral culture no resources could be found whenever I try to use a language resource.

I couldn't find the Access Modifier anywhere in the .resx or in the GUI. I have searched all over the internet, but no such option is present for me (Visual Studio 2010 Pro). Any other suggestions?

Comment: See this: http://picpaste.com/Untitled_3.png. _Access modifier_ in the document toolbar.

Comment: Thank you very much. The Access modifier option wasn't present at the position in your screenshot. However I changed the following line in the resource.designer file to refer to my assembly and after that the option was suddenly there. It is working flawlessly now.

Dim temp As Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager = New Global.System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyAssemblyName.Resource", GetType(Resource).Assembly)

PS: Is there a way to upvote your comment or mark as solution as in other forums? Haven't seen any

PPS: What the hell? stackoverflow is suddenly ignoring new lines!?

Comment: No, I'd suggest to do **not** manually edit designer generated files (if things will work or...you change anything that changes will be out-of-sync or dropped). Try "clean" way: delete all .designer.cs for your resources to import, add .resx files in your project, open each one and select right access modifier then save them. Now .designer.cs should be generated again (and now in sync)...

Comment: This is working now. I must have messed up something in my project before, because the access modifier option simply wasn't there. I've just tried with a new project and this time it was there by default.